# What is the code flow at the backend of wordpress-woocommerce?For example how the order listing is loaded at backend?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am not able to find which template, action and database query I can look for the back-end of woocommerce(for example order list page).

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please take a few minutes to read these guidelines about how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the Woocommerce template files, you can find them at 'wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates'. You can do this by accessing your site's backend through an FTP client.

The template for Orders in the My Account Page can be found at the myaccount folder with a file named orders.php

Here is the full documentation on where to find the template files and how to override them. https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/